# Prove that the covariance of 2 linear combinations of random variables is the linear combination of the covariances

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance, covariance

How would you prove the following property about covariances?

[image]

I found it here:

https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_1_covariance_correlation.php

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to prove for suitable random variables $X,Y,Z$ and constant $a$ that:

- $\mathsf{Cov}(X+Y,Z)=\mathsf{Cov}(X,Z)+\mathsf{Cov}(Y,Z)$
- $\mathsf{Cov}(aX,Y)=a\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)$
- $\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathsf{Cov}(Y,X)$

which can be done on base of definition of $\mathsf{Cov}$.

The first two bullets show that $\mathsf{Cov}$ is linear on first argument.

The third bullet makes it possible to show that this is also the case for the second argument.

Comment: I don't understand your last point about the 3rd bullet. Why does it justify the linearity of covariance for the second argument?

Comment: $\mathsf{Cov}(Z,X+Y)=\mathsf{Cov}(X+Y,Z)=\mathsf{Cov}(X,Z)+\mathsf{Cov}(Y,Z)=\mathsf{Cov}(Z,X)+\mathsf{Cov}(Z,Y)$. The first and last equality on base of third bullet. Similarly it can be proved that $\mathsf{Cov}(X,aY)=a\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)$.

Comment: I follow the logic what you did, but I struggle to understand how your reasoning proves the equation in my question.

Comment: Have you tried to prove the equality for small numbers $n,m$ already? Such as $n=2,m=1$ and $n=2,m=2$. Formally you can prove it with induction on $n+m$ where $n$ and $m$ are positive integers.

Comment: For a function $f$ that satisfies $f(X+Y)=f(X)+f(Y)$ and $f(aX)=af(X)$ it can be proved with induction on $n$ that $f(\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i)=\sum_{i=1}^na_if(X_i)$. The cases $n=1,2$ are direct and if $n>2$ then you split up the sum in two terms that are both sums again and both having a number of terms $\leq n$. Something like $f(S)=f(S_1+S_2)=f(S_1)+f(S_2)$ where $f(S_1)$ and $f(S_2)$ can be worked out on base of induction hypothese.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the result $Cov(aX+bY,cW+dZ)=abCov(X,Y)+acCov(X,W)+bcCov(Y,W)+bdCov(Y,Z)$ as follows.

$$\begin{split}Cov(aX+bY,cW+dZ)&=E[(aX+bY-E(aX+bY))(cW+dZ-E(cW+dZ))]\\
&=E[(a(X-E(X)+b(Y-E(Y))(c(W-E(W)+d(Z-E(Z))]\\
&=E[ac(X-E(X))(W-E(W))]+E[ad(X-E(X))(Z-E(Z))+E[bc(Y-E(Y))(W-E(W))]+E[bd(Y-E(Y))(Z-E(Z))]]\\
&=acCov(X,W)+adCov(X,Z)+bcCov(Y,W)+bdCov(Y,Z)\end{split}$$

Repeated application of this gives the desired result.